# How to make a function that would calculate based on progression?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game, and each time you click the button - you buy "kiosk" (cash reduced, kiosks increased, buildings increased). Additional "kiosk" is 100$ more expensive than the previous one (mathematical progression). I was wondering what function could calculate total money spent on buying them at any given point. Here is my code:

```
var game = {
    cash: 0,
    kiosks: 0,
    shops: 0,
    banks: 0,
    buildingsNo: 0,
    totalIncome: 0,
    cashSpent: 0,
    buyKiosk: function(){
        if(this.cash>(1+this.kiosks)*100){
            this.cash -= (1+this.kiosks)*100;
            this.kiosks++;
            this.buildingsNo++;
            amount1.innerHTML = this.kiosks;
            price1.innerHTML = "$"+(1+this.kiosks)*100;
            log("Kiosk nupirktas!")
        }else{
            log("Nepakanka pinigu kioskui!");
        }
    },
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, and that code is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, you do not need whole code to answer this. So main question, thingA costs 100, thingB costs 200, thingC costs 300 and so on. We have total number of things on "kiosks" element. What function would calculate total money spent at any point? (for example using above example now it would be 600) I want to do a stat div that would periodically update it.

Comment: If it's something you're going to be displaying periodically, why not just track it in a variable?  A few bytes of memory is likely a better tradeoff than always calculating it on the fly.  And, if you ever added a mechanic that broke the normal progression (a free kiosk, a half-price kiosk, etc.) you wouldn't have to rework your calculation to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

The [formula for finding the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) is:

```
sum(N) = N * (N + 1) / 2
```

Then you just need to multiply the answer by 100 in order to scale to your progression amount.

```
function calculateKioskCost(numKiosks) {
    return numKiosks * (numKiosks + 1) * 50;
}
```

You should document this formula in the comments of the function.